# upload image dynamically in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I want to make a product presentation page where I retrieved the addresses of the images, then I have but the address that I retrieved it but the image does not upload (the link is correct).I found some source which said that you have to use require ('../ image / name_image.jpg') when I have but the code like it works but when I used list.image (variable) it does not work

the result that i got it [image]

the code that creates the image [image]

get data results [image]

file structure [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your image folder inside the public folder: *public/image/*
then use `<img src="/image/m1.jpg" />`

Comment: Moving directory image to public directory isn't a good idea, the images should stay in the src directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and you need to declare state images with empty array, and declare the function loadImages that will load your images dynamically:

```
 loadImages() {
    lists.forEach((item, i) => 
    import(item.image)
      .then(image => {
        this.setState(state => ({ images: [...state.images, image] }))
      })      
    )
 }
```

In your jsx edit this line:

```
src={this.state.images[index]}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it return Error: Cannot find module '../image/m1_c2.jpg'

Comment: You need to verify if the image m1_c2.jpg exists in the directory image, you can also try my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use:

<img src={require(`../image/m1.jpg`)}/>